# Tab space in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I want to use a tab space in my string. I am providing the code of using new line. But I don't know how to use a tab space in a string. Can anyone help me on this !?

```
"Warning ! Sorry Cash Pay is less than this  <br/> month\'s installment. Please pay the  <br/> right amount."
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`&#09;` is TAB character in ASCII. But according to html spec all white space characters will be stripped to a single character. There are other white space characters too. Like `&thinsp;`, `&emsp;` and `&ensp;` You can try them too.

### Update

It seems `&emsp;` gives a spacing of tab size. See the following

- `a&emsp;b` rendered as **a b**
- `a&ensp;b` rendered as **a b**
- `a&thinsp;b` rendered as **a b**
- `a&nbsp;b` rendered as **a b**
- `a&#09;b` rendered as **a b**

Answer (score 0):

If you put your string in an HTML `<pre>` element then it can have a tab character. String `"Warning! \t error"` set to be put into the innerHTML of `<pre id="output"></pre>` will result in
:`Warning!      error`.

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631646/how-to-preserve-whitespace-indentation-of-text-enclosed-in-html-pre-tags-exclu

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `&nbsp` (non-breaking spaces) for making white spaces in HTML lines.

```
"Warning ! Sorry Cash Pay is less than this &nbsp;&nbsp; month\'s installment. Please pay the  &nbsp; right amount."
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a single space, Type `&nbsp;`

If you want to add 2 spaces, Type `&ensp;`

If you want to add 4 spaces, Type `&emsp;` *(4 spaces is a `tab` space)*