# VSCode - indenting adds spaces around strings

Tags: html, vue.js, visual-studio-code, prettier

I am using Vue 3 & Prettier w/ VS Code. Whenever I have a string on it's own line, it gets formatted how I want it. The problem... My Dev Tool browser renders strings with spaces around them. I need strings to render without spaces so my tests can pass. The code below:

```
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo voluptatibus quae, eveniet quia
  pariatur cupiditate exercitationem aut incidunt natus, possimus delectus commodi! Deleniti,
  dignissimos aliquam numquam voluptatibus qui dolores neque!
</div>
```

Looks like this in my Dev Tools.

[image]

Another example:

```
<div>
    testing
</div>
```

Render likes:
[image]

Comment: That whitespace is actually there: it's the collapsed linebreaks and indentation. That is the beauty of HTML: you can format your code without affecting rendering (except for certain `white-space` values...). If your testing is affected by this, then that's the issue, not this. For example, see [myf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77374097/15261914).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are testing [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property, right?

Solution could be changing tested property to **[`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)** instead:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('div')].forEach(_=>{
_.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',
  `<code>${_.style.cssText}</code>:
  <br>- .innerText: ${verbalizeWhitespace(_.innerText)}
  <br>- .textContent: ${verbalizeWhitespace(_.textContent)}`
)});

function verbalizeWhitespace(str) {
 return '»<code>' + str.replace(
  /\s/g,
  (m) => `<mark>[${
   { '\n': '\\n'
   , '\t': 'tab'
   , ' ': 'sp'
   }[m] || m.charCodeAt(0)
  }]</mark>`) + '</code>«';
}
```

```css
html {
  color-scheme: light dark;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: color-mix(in srgb, currentcolor 50%, transparent);
  font-size: .7em;
  word-spacing: 1em;
}

mark {
  padding: .3ch;
  margin: .5ch;
}
```

```html
<div style="white-space: normal;">
 A B 
 C D
</div>
<div style="white-space: pre;">
 A B 
 C D
</div>
<!--
N.B.: There are also spaces between "B"s and a newlines.
-->
```

As demonstrated, `innerText` even reflects whether whitespace in the element is supposed to be significant for rendered outcome (preformated text) or not.

What you see in the devtools inspector is just a hint that there is in fact some whitespace in the DOM (and presumably in the source code), but unless given element is (styled as) preformatted, it should not have any impact on rendering.

In cases when you DO have `white-space` set to `pre`, `pre-wrap`, then all whitespace (leading, trailing, "indentation") matters. Then it is similar question to: [How can I ignore leading and trailing linebreaks within an html "code" block using css, javascript or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946908).

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo voluptatibus quae, eveniet quia
  pariatur cupiditate exercitationem aut incidunt natus, possimus delectus commodi! Deleniti,
  dignissimos aliquam numquam voluptatibus qui dolores neque!</div>
```

or

```html
<div><!--
  -->Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo voluptatibus quae, eveniet quia
  pariatur cupiditate exercitationem aut incidunt natus, possimus delectus commodi! Deleniti,
  dignissimos aliquam numquam voluptatibus qui dolores neque!<!--
--></div>
```