# How can I get the correct indentation using the HTML <code> element?

Tags: html

I am creating a documentation page and in one section I attempt to explain the anatomy of the HTML document. In the final outcome, it does not show the correct indentation.

Code:

```
<p>
   <code>
      &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
      &lt;html lang="en-US" dir="ltr"&gt;
      &lt;head&gt;
      &lt;meta charset="utf-8"&gt;
      &lt;meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"&gt;
      &lt;title&gt;Title Name&lt;/title&gt;
      &lt;/head&gt;
      &lt;body&gt;
      &lt;h1&gt;This is a headline.&lt;/h1&gt;
      &lt;p&gt;1st paragraph.&lt;/p&gt;
      &lt;p&gt;Usually there's quite a lot here.&lt;/p&gt;
      &lt;/body&gt;
      &lt;/html&gt;
   </code>
 </p>
```

I even added physical indentations and it is still not evident in the final result.

```
<p>
   <code>
      &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
      &lt;html lang="en-US" dir="ltr"&gt;
        &lt;head&gt;
          &lt;meta charset="utf-8"&gt;
      &lt;meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"&gt;
      &lt;title&gt;Title Name&lt;/title&gt;
        &lt;/head&gt;
        &lt;body&gt;
          &lt;h1&gt;This is a headline.&lt;/h1&gt;
          &lt;p&gt;1st paragraph.&lt;/p&gt;
          &lt;p&gt;Usually there's quite a lot here.&lt;/p&gt;
          &lt;/body&gt;
        &lt;/html&gt;
   </code>
 </p>
```

[Final outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFzUT.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use indentation in a <code> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646408/how-do-i-use-indentation-in-a-code-tag)

Answer (score 0):

The semantics of the [`<code>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code) don't imply that whitespace is significant.

Combine it with a [`<pre>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) (instead of using a paragraph).

Answer (score 0):

This property should be what you are looking for:

```css
code {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: Seems pretty extreme to change the way every div works.

Comment: Your right, I made a mistake, I was thinking about the "code" tag. Corrected it.. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Use [`pre`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) instead of [`code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code). The text in `pre` is "typically rendered using a non-proportional, or monospaced, font. Whitespace inside this element is displayed as written."

Comment: No. The HTML example is code. `pre` should be used **with** `code` (in this case), not instead of it.

Comment: Agreed; however, if the question is 'how to keep formatting using whitespace' `pre` would suffice. Another option would, of course, be to replace all spaces with `&nbsp;`...

Answer (score -2):

A code tag doesn't honor whitespace.  The easiest fix is to wrap the code with pre.

```
<p>
  <pre>
      <code>
     
       ... your code
      </code>
  <pre>
</p>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<pre>` element may not be a child of a `<code>` element (or a descendant of a `<p>` element).

Comment: If that bothers you then wrap the code with the pre.